# Save and Reuse the model PULP CPLEX

Tags: cplex, pulp

I need to use again the model, because it is very long and delay in being built, so how can I use the model again to be solved by fixing some variables and leaving others free to find a result.

I´m try:

```
***** Buil model and save in external file ****
pickle.dump(prob, open('modelo.pkl', 'wb'))
***** Solve problem ****
prob.solve(solver)
***** read again problem  ****
prob = pickle.load(open("modelo.pkl","rb"))
***** fix some variable result problem  ****
carro[1,1].setInitialValue(200)
carro[1,1].fixValue()
carro[2,1].setInitialValue(500)
carro[2,1].fixValue()
***** Solve again problem ****
prob.solve(solver)
```

Answer (score 0):

let me use the [zoo and bus example](https://medium.com/@alexfleischer_84755/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-66940178db6) to show you

```
import pulp
import cplex

bus_problem = pulp.LpProblem("bus", pulp.LpMinimize)

nbBus40 = pulp.LpVariable('nbBus40', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
nbBus30 = pulp.LpVariable('nbBus30', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

# Objective function
bus_problem += 500 * nbBus40 + 400 * nbBus30, "cost"

# Constraints
bus_problem += 40 * nbBus40 + 30 * nbBus30 >= 300

#fix nbBus40
bus_problem += nbBus40==2

bus_problem.solve(pulp.CPLEX())
print(pulp.LpStatus[bus_problem.status])

for variable in bus_problem.variables():
    print ("{} = {}".format(variable.name, variable.varValue))
```

gives

```
Optimal
nbBus30 = 8.0
nbBus40 = 2.0
```

or

```
import pulp
import cplex

bus_problem = pulp.LpProblem("bus", pulp.LpMinimize)

nbBus40 = pulp.LpVariable('nbBus40', lowBound=2, upBound=2, cat='Integer')
nbBus30 = pulp.LpVariable('nbBus30', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

# Objective function
bus_problem += 500 * nbBus40 + 400 * nbBus30, "cost"

# Constraints
bus_problem += 40 * nbBus40 + 30 * nbBus30 >= 300



bus_problem.solve(pulp.CPLEX())
print(pulp.LpStatus[bus_problem.status])

for variable in bus_problem.variables():
    print ("{} = {}".format(variable.name, variable.varValue))
```

which gives the same but with no additional constraint

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer, but I need to fix some variables without add constrainst to problem, because my problem have aproximatly 7 milions and 500.000 variables. So if I fix with your style increase the number of constrainst. Do you know other way ?